# Spring Batch Asynchronous Job Execution

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

When I launch large(20-30) jobs in quick succession with different params, the job gets stuck in between and does not show any exception.

I am using Async job controller with Thread Pool Executor. My Job has one step where I have used partition to split into multiple parallel slave steps.

When I run the flow with smaller number of jobs then the whole flow works fine.

Comment: What's the size of your thread pool?

Comment: I have tried with 10 and 50 thread pool size. The issue is with the increment logic for unique identifiers of metadata tables which causes db locking when multiple parallel jobs execute the partition step at same time. Which DB is preferable in multi-threaded environment where I do not care much about persisting spring batch state.

Comment: Are you using the Map based job repository? If yes, that could be the issue. I recommend using a Jdbc based job repository with an in-memory db (like h2, hsql, etc).